# Extending a type to have multiple values for the same associatedtype

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

Coming up with an accurate title was a little difficult so I'll demonstrate my issue with a simple example. I want to create a protocol that specifies that an adherer is able to be transformed into a different type:

```
protocol Transformable {
    associatedtype TransformableTo
    func transform() -> TransformableTo
}
```

Then create specific protocols for each type:

```
protocol DoubleTransformable: Transformable where TransformableTo == Double {}
```

So that if, for example, I want Strings to be able to be converted into Doubles, I would write:

```
extension String: DoubleTransformable {
    func transform() -> Double {
        return Double(self)
    }
}
```

This works great until I want to have a given type conform to more than of these "specific" transformable contracts:

```
protocol DecimalTransformable: Transformable where TransformableTo == Decimal {}
extension String: DecimalTransformable {
    func transform() -> Decimal {
        ...
    }
}
```

The compiler barks at me on the String extension above since the `TransformableTo` type for `DecimalTransformable` clashes with the `TransformableTo` type for `DoubleTransformable`. This makes sense to me but I'm not seeing a workaround. Any advice on how to solve this and/or a different direction that accomplishes the same thing would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Adding some more context about the use case to help address some of the questions in the comments. This is a simplified version of the actual code so this might seem a little strange, but I think it gets the point across.

I have two structs, one represents a public-facing model and one represents data that "backs" the model. I don't want to expose the data in the PrivateModel to clients so the PublicModel acts as middleman between PrivateModel and the client. The issue I'm trying to solve is that sometimes the type of a PrivateModel property is different than what I want the PublicModel's corresponding property to be (and changing the type of PrivateModel is a non-starter).

```
struct PrivateModel {
    var date: String { return "Jan. 1, 1970" }
}
```

```
struct PublicModel {
    private let privateModel: PrivateModel

    init(source: PrivateModel) {
        self.privateModel = source
    }

    var date: Date {
        return self.privateModel.date.transform()
    }
}
```

Note the call to `transform` within the public model. My actual goal here is to have a single transformation method that I can call on any type object, where the generic return type of `transform` is inferred by the type of property whose getter I'm inside.

Comment: `associatedtype = TransformableTo` doesn't make any sense. You mean `associatedtype TransformableTo`

Comment: Correct -- edited

Comment: The problem here as I see it has to do with polymorphism (method overloading) only works when the method parameters changes but not the return value and also with the fact that if the protocol contains one method then a conforming type can only implement _one_ version of this method. I was playing around with having two associated types a "from" and a "to" and also by changing the signature of the method instead only having an associated type "to" but as an argument to the method but I failed to get either to work.

Comment: Furthermore to Joakim's point - the `Transformable` protocol specifies that a conforming type will define a *concrete* type for `TransformableTo` - either `Double` or `Decimal` or any other type - and that is what the `transform` would return. So, it can't be different ones. Most common way to run into problems with generics and/or protocols is when you start by trying to define a protocol, instead of start with a specific case, then add another one, *then* see if having a protocol even makes sense. So... how do you plan to use such a type? Then, what is the use case that requires a protocol?

Comment: Resuming associated type is not generic. I agree with New Dev regarding the need to use a protocol. This can be easily resolved by extending String and creating some generic methods

Comment: Edited the question to give some more background/context

Comment: What role are any of the protocols playing in this? If you just deleted the protocols entirely, it looks like it would work exactly as you expect. (I don't like overloaded return types; I think they're a hassle to work with and aren't giving you enough benefit here to be worth the trouble, but that's mostly taste. But there doesn't seem any reason to have a protocol at all.)

Comment: @WongWray try creating a generic structure

Comment: It's a good point, Rob. Honestly it was to make things a bit more explicit with what's going on when seeing the `transform()` call. Seeing `extension String: DoubleTransformable` seemed easier to readily understand than having to comb through an extension that contains several different versions of `func transform()`. Plus, for developers other than myself who would come across the `transform()` call inside the getter, XCode would direct them to the protocol which I preferred. But if what I'm going for here isn't possible then deleting the protocols entirely seems like the way to go

Comment: @LeoDabus generic struct was one of the first things I tried but I ran into the same issue as what I have above. I wasn't able to find a way to make a given type transformable to more than one type. Though admittedly my attempt was using an associatedtype so perhaps there's another way without associatedtypes that I'm not seeing?

Comment: `DoubleTransformable` is fine if you're trying to capture intent. But you should absolutely get rid of `Transformable`. It doesn't actually express anything, unless you want to make it an empty protocol purely for documentation purposes. A type cannot conform to the same protocol multiple ways.

Comment: I would definitely ask yourself if this situation is happening so much over so many kinds of types (and that every one of those types should transform exactly the same way), to make all of this worthwhile vs just clearly writing `Double(self) ?? 0` in a few places. For example, will every String that needs to be a Date be in the same format? If any Strings will ever be in a different format, or need different default values for missing data, then the value drops very quickly.

Comment: Good questions. As of now, yes every instance of transformation from a given type to another should happen in the same way. The first attempt at this actually attempted to use conversion blocks (which would allow for variable methods of "transforming") but that route was decided against. It's seeming more and more like simple extensions with overloaded `transform`s is the way to go. Not the most elegant but I think proper documentation will make it easier to grok

Comment: From your last example the use case seems to be that you are always transforming to a given type so you could have extensions with methods like `transformToDate()`, `transformToDouble()` etc to ignore a clash of definitions. Not sure if protocols would make a difference though.

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer to your question but as others have already mentioned associated types are not generic. What you need is a generic method. To accomplish what you want and cover most numeric types you need to conform the generic type to LosslessStringConvertible protocol as well. Note that the use of a protocol is not necessary and can be removed. I would do something like this:

```
protocol NumericTransformable {
    func numeric<N: Numeric & LosslessStringConvertible>() -> N?
}
```

---

```
extension String: NumericTransformable {
    func numeric<N: Numeric & LosslessStringConvertible>() -> N?  { N(self) }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
let double: Double? = "123.45".numeric()       // 123.45
let float: Float? = "123.45".numeric()         // 123.45
let float80: Float80? = "123.45".numeric()     // 123.45
let int: Int? = "123".numeric()                // 123
```

---

Note also that Decimal and CGFloat types do not conform to `LosslessStringConvertible`:

```
extension CGFloat: LosslessStringConvertible {
    private static let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    public init?(_ description: String) {
        guard let cgFloat = Self.formatter.number(from: description) as? CGFloat else { return nil }
        self = cgFloat
    }
}
```

---

```
extension Decimal: LosslessStringConvertible {
    public init?(_ description: String) {
        guard let decimal = Decimal(string: description) else { return nil }
        self = decimal
    }
}
```

---

```
let cgfloat: CGFloat? = "123.45".numeric()     //  123.45
let decimal: Decimal? = "123.45".numeric()     //  123.45
```

Comment: Really appreciate the info. This probably doesn't help for my specific situation since I need something that works for not just numerics but other types (including custom types) as well, but still a clever approach. Thanks!

Comment: Also, I think there's a typo on the `let int` line. `numeric()` wouldn't return 123.45 in that scenario, right?