# Accept Float, Double or Int in Swift `init` to convert to String

Tags: swift

I'm attempting to convert a value to a string in an `init`. That value can be an `Int`, `Double`, or `Float`.

For example:

```
struct example {
    var string: String
    
    init(number: Int) {
        string = String(number)
    }
}
```

I would like to say something like below (I'm using Typescript as an example - this obviously doesn't work, but I want number to be any of those three types - all of which `String` can convert).

```
struct example {
    var string: String
    
    init(number: Int | Float | Double) {
        string = String(number)
    }
}
```

---

Edit: I realized I have another issue. I need to convert back from a string to the type of Int or Double or Float. Using one of the answers below, I'm trying to figure out how to implement `getNumberWith5`:

```
struct example2<N: Numeric & CustomStringConvertible>: CustomStringConvertible {
    @Binding var number: N
    
    init(number: Binding<N>) {
        self._number = number
    }
    var description: String {
        String(describing: number)
    }
    
    mutating func getNumberWith5() {
        // How do I update number to the type N?
        self.number = howDoIConvertToN(description + "5")
    }
}
```

Or from another answer:

```
struct example3<N: Numeric> {

    @Binding var number: N
    var string: String

    init(number: Binding<N>) {
        self._number = number
        self.string = "\(number)"
    }
    
    mutating func getNumberWith5() {
        // How do I update number to the type N?
        self.number = howDoIConvertToN(string + "5")
    }
}
```

---

Edit2 My Answer:

I attempted to create an equivalent of type unions (as Typescript has) using `enums` in Swift based on [this article](https://camlittle.com/posts/type-unions-in-swift/). But it was challenging to then assign back to that value. I've decided Swift just doesn't have first class support for type unions like Typescript has. So, I used the accepted answer below and this seems to work.

```
extension String {
    func numeric<N: Numeric & LosslessStringConvertible>() -> N? {
        N(self)
    }
}

struct example4<N: Numeric & LosslessStringConvertible> {
    @State var string: String
    @Binding var number: N

    init(number: Binding<N>) {
        self._number = number
        self.string = String(describing: number)
    }

    mutating func getNumberWith5() {
        let newString = string + "5"
        number = newString.numeric() ?? 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Just write three initialisers, one for each type you want to initialise with.

Comment: Use Binding.constant for the first way or _number =

Comment: Why `@Binding` now ? are you using SwiftUI ?

Comment: @AnderCover I am. But the generic question is how to convert a strong back to the type N of that conforms to those protocols

Comment: It was just to be sure, your first edit made me think that maybe you wanted to access the projected value of a property wrapper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually if all you want is a string representation of `Int` `Float` `Double` or any other standard numeric type you only need to know that they conform to `CustomStringConvertible` and use `String(describing:)`.

Or you can use conformance to [`Numeric`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/numeric) **and** [`CustomStringConvertible`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible):

```
struct example {
    var string: String
    
    init<C: CustomStringConvertible & Numeric>(number: C) {
        string = String(describing: number)
    }
}
```

and maybe even better `example` itself could conform to `CustomStringConvertible`

```
struct example: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String
    
    init<C: CustomStringConvertible & Numeric>(number: C) {
        description = String(describing: number)
    }
}
```

yet another way :

```
struct example<N: Numeric & CustomStringConvertible>: CustomStringConvertible {
    let number: N
    init(number: N) {
        self.number = number
    }
    var description: String {
        String(describing: number)
    }
}
```

#### EDIT

I think what you want is a custom [Property Wrapper](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID617) not `@Binding`:

```
@propertyWrapper struct CustomStringConversion<Wrapped: CustomStringConvertible> {
    var wrappedValue: Wrapped

    init(wrappedValue: Wrapped) {
        self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue
    }
    
    var projectedValue: String { .init(describing: wrappedValue) }
}

struct Foo {
    @CustomStringConversion var number = 5
}

let foo = Foo()
let number: Int = foo.number // 5
let stringRepresentation: String = foo.$number // "5"
```

But as @LeoDabus pointed out [using `LosslessStringConvertible`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65958622/extending-a-type-to-have-multiple-values-for-the-same-associatedtype/65960326#65960326) may be better :

```
struct example<N: Numeric & LosslessStringConvertible>: LosslessStringConvertible {
    let number: N
    
    init(number: N) {
        self.number = number
    }
    
    init?(_ description: String) {
        guard let number = N(description) else { return nil }
        self.number = number
    }
    
    var description: String {
        .init(number)
    }
}

let bar = example(number: Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude) // 1.7976931348623157e+308
let baz: example<Double>? = example("1.7976931348623157e+308") // 1.7976931348623157e+308
```

Comment: **Discussion
Calling this property directly is discouraged. Instead, convert an instance of any type to a string by using the String(describing:) initializer. This initializer works with any type, and uses the custom description property for types that conform to CustomStringConvertible:**

Comment: Thank you for this, I updated my question for a follow on question I realize I was going to hit as I implemented this. It's how to convert the string back to type "N" in your example.

Comment: Indeed @LeoDabus, that does not change the fact that one should use the protocol IMHO. Edited! thanks for the remark

Comment: Never said that that the protocol approach was incorrect. I would use `LosslessStringConvertible` instead. This would leave a few numeric types out of it but `Int`, `Float`, and `Double` do conform to it.

Comment: @Diesel regarding the second part of your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/65960326/2303865

Comment: Yes, `LosslessStringConvertible` may make even more sense, I'll edit again.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I added an edit with the route I chose to go. I'm still confused on why the string extension `N(self)` works though.

Comment: if you check the `LosslessStringConvertible` documentation you'll see that the only requirement for conforming types is `init?(_ description: String)`. Concretly it means that `Int`, `Float` or `Double` which conform to `LosslessStringConvertible` implement that initializer. In `String.numeric()` the compiler knows that `N` conforms to `LosslessStringConvertible` and therefore can infer that `N(self)` refers to it's requirement

Answer (score 2):

Use generic structure with Numeric protocol.

```
struct Example<T:Numeric> {
    var string: String
    init(number: T) {
        self.string = "\(number)"
    }
}
```

Comment: No need for the whole struct to be generic, you only need to make the init generic.

Comment: Thank you, I updated my question with a follow on. How would I convert the string back to the generic type "T"

Comment: Better to use one T type var ane use computed property for string

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Example {
    var string: String
    
    init(number: Int) {
        string = String(number)
    }
    init(number: Float) {
        string = String(number)
    }
    init(number: Double) {
        string = String(number)
    }
}
```

Comment: This appears to be the most "right" answer, which is that it cannot be done in one init for just an Int / Float / Double. But another answer above helps answer my question more generically.

Answer (score -1):

You can have a look at how swift does this with its String-initializer:

```
struct Example {
    init<Number>(number: Number) where Number: BinaryInteger {
        string = String(number)
    }
}
```